# TypeORM return decimal number with extra scale

Tags: oracle, typeorm

I am using Node.js with TypeScript connecting to the oracle database using TypeORM. I am facing one weird issue that is when I am fetching a record from the database it returns the value with extra scale numbers.

eg. If the actual value stored in the database is 99.1 then it returns 99.10000000000001

I have defined field in entity file as

```
  @Column({ name: 'weight', precision: 20, scale: 2, nullable: true })
  weight!: number;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you're retrieving this value into a variable. What is the data type of this variable? You might want to [read this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)